# The @use feature of Sass

Tags: css, import, sass

First of all, I hope someone can actually understand this rambling question because I'm struggling to even word what I mean in a coherent way, but here goes:

I don't know why I'm struggling so much to figure this out, but I've been using @import with SCSS for a while now and feel I have my head around it fairly well, but now I want to use the @use rule since the phasing out of @import is a thing. And I can't find any videos or any real articles explaining how to use it properly.

The problem I'm having is I can't get my head around how to actually use it, I feel like I get the basic idea, and how to use the modules in each partial (I think..), but I feel like I don't understand how to actually get all of the partials into a main .scss file to be compiled into css.. This is hard to explain.. I just feel like I would still need to @import at least the files that have @use inside them into a main file for it to be compiled.. I'm guessing this obviously isn't the case, but otherwise I can't work it out.. Do I just @use all the files I want imported into the main file or..?

If anyone could shed some light on this for me, I would be really grateful.

Thanks

Comment: Sass-lang provides documentation on how to use it properly: https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/use

Comment: Thanks, I’ve looked through that so many times and I still just can’t get my head around it. I’ll have to go through it again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**The new rules `@use`/`@forward` and the remove from `@import` are indeed a really big impact to SASS.** It leads to a complete new form to write sass. A try to make an easy explanation for the beginning to use the new technique:

(1) `@use` works similar to `@import`. It adds the code from a (config- or partial-)file or a module to your stylesheet.

(2) The difference is: SASS changes the scope of variables/mixins/functions from global (all imported files = one scope) to local files (variables are only valid in the actual file). If you need to use variables/mixins/functions from another (config- or partial-)file you need to 'include' them to the actual file first.

That means for your project(*):

```
//file ###> _config.scss

$columnWidth: 50%;
$projectColors: (
   primary: red,
   secondary: blue,
);


//file ###> _functions.scss 

@use 'config' as * // --> to use config vars (here: without namespace)

@function getColor( $name ){
   $color: map-get($projectColors, $name);  
   @return $color;
}


//file ###> _partial.scss

@use 'config' as *     // --> use config vars (here: without namespace)
@use 'functions' as *  // --> use functions (here: without namespace)

.class {
   width: $width;
   color: getColor( primary );
}


//file ###> myStylesheet.scss
// no need to @use 'config' or 'functions' 
// as they are not direct needed in this file

@use 'partial'  //--> write the css

---
```

*( * ) Including files without using a namespace is a special case to make the example more easy. Normaly you will include variables/mixins/functions to a separated namespace and call them by `namespace.$variable` or `namespace.mixin`. And there are techniques to move special settings to a `@used` file as well so you can move variable settings to the project. Please have a look to official and excelent description: https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/use*

---

**NOTES:**

(1) As it is heavily discussed: Yes. This is INDEED the intended new way to work with SASS. (https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/2750)

(2) Very interesting: The actual brandnew version from Bootstrap has moved to the new Sass Version. But as I have seen Bootstrap does not use that new feature `@use` and still works with `@import`. That may have reasons ... and it seems not to easy to change the technique.

(3) Also it seems to be a little bit complicated there are some advantages comming with that new technique. Using separate namespaces make it much mor easier to work with external modules without causing name conflicts.

Comment: Frustratingly I tried this all, and when I @use in the main scss file to be compiled into CSS it just shows "@use 'global'" in the css file.. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong, I'm following the official SASS article and your answer which both are obviously correct.. But it's not working.

Comment: @JamesPointer Really hard to help without knowing more ... but maybe ... are you sure you are using a compiler which understands the actual version `DartSass`. There are a lot compilers which are not updated yet. Maybe you like to check that.  (see for example in vsCode: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66193156/live-sass-compiler-use-causes-compilation-error/66207572#66207572)

Comment: `as * ` was what I needed. Also realising that you need to reference files directly (you can't have one file that imports everything and import that one file). Thanks!