# When importing a file with @use then: Error Undefined Mixin

Tags: sass

I have a entry file:

```
@use '_mixins';
@use '_default';
```

Now when I use a mixin in `default.scss` it throws the error:

> Dart Sass failed with this error: Error: Undefined mixin.

Since `@use` is encouraged I don't understand why this doesn't work. If I write `@import` like in the olden days it works well:

```
@import '_mixins';
@import '_default';
```

This way all is nice and dandy.

How do I have to use `@use` and still have everything available?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That may be because the use of the new rule `@use` has an high impact to the way  you build your project structure. Using of `@use`changes it dramatically:

1. With `@import` you add a file and the mixins/vars/modules are ready to use in every sass file you load later on.
2. With `@use` you have to load the special sass file you need (i.e. '_mixins') direct in the file where you want to use it direct ... not to the main file. (Yes: loading the mixins/functions/variables-files to EVERY single partial file where you want to use them is the NEW INTENDED way to write sass.
3. And one more point to your using of `@use`: If you load by `@use 'mixins` you have to call the mixin in your file in the separated namespace `@include mixins.yourMixinYouCall`. If you want to load the mixins without separated namespace you can do: `@use 'mixins' as *`.

This changing to seperate namespace has some advantages. But indeed that is a really big impact and a very hard discussed theme about the new way to build your sass files.

We had this this week and before posting that twice you may have a look to this posting:

[The @use feature of Sass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66291838/the-use-feature-of-sass/66300336#66300336)

Comment: So it works in a similar fashion like those various js import flavors. Not a fan to be honest. Thanks for clearing things up.