# SCSS switching from @import to @use: undefined mixin

Tags: sass, undefined, scss-mixins

For many years I've been completely happy with @import, but times, they are a-changing ...

So I try to shift my projects from @import to @use and @forward, and I found [this posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66291838/the-use-feature-of-sass/66300336#66300336) quite useful. But when I try to implement @use into my partials, I keep getting an 'undefined mixin'. I think I may have misunderstood the way @use works, but I can't for the live of me figure out where i went wrong. I've reached the point where I just want to climb the next church tower and start shooting people ... which doesn't help me concentrating either ;)

So I stripped it all down to very basic chunks of code to examine the problem under 'lab conditions'. Here is what I came up whith:

Folders and files:

```
styles.scss
├── a_tools
│   └── _mixins.scss
├── b_settings
│   └── _global.scss
└── c-components
    └── _test.scss
```

---

_mixins.scss:

```
@use '../b_settings/global' as *;

@function bp($bp) {
  @return ($breakpoints, $bp);
}

@mixin vp-medium {
  @media (min-width: #{breakpoints(small) + 1}) and (max-width: #{breakpoints(medium)}) {
    @content;
  }
}
```

---

_gobal.scss:

```
$breakpoints: (
  'small':                                  767px,
  'medium':                                 1024px,
  'navigation':                             840px,
);

:root {
  --vp-name:                                small;
}

@include vp-medium {
  :root {
    --vp-name:                              medium;
  }
}
```

---

_test.scss:

```
@use 'a_tools/mixins' as *;
@use 'b_settings/global' as *;

.test {
  margin: 10px;

  @include vp-medium {
    margin: 20px;
  }
}
```

---

styles.scss:

```
@use 'c_components/test';
```

Compiling keeps throwing 'undefined mixin on line 15, column 1 of _global.scss', which is the line '@include vp-medium {'. Compiled with Dart Sass 1.32.8.

Who can tell me where I got on the wrong path? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand the new ruls `@use` the way, that you have to `@use`the needed files with the needed mixin to EVERY file you want to use it.

If I did get it reight:

You `@used` the file `mixins` with mixin `vp-medium` in `test.scss` where it is used.

But you did not `@use` the same file in `global` where want to use the mixin as well. Just try to `@use` the file also to `global`.

ADDITIONAL:

We had similar discussion here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66300336/9268485

Comment: Mate, that seemed to be the problem! Thanks a lot! I have to get my brain around the fact that you can't build "import chains" anymore. Personally I do not like the new appoach at all, it solves problems I never had and forces me to write more code.

But at least I got it working finally. Thanks again! :)