# how to set up scss folder structure using @use with dart-sass?

Tags: sass, dart-sass

For a while I have been using the @import to create the following SCSS folder structure. to import the 3 partials into _utilities-dir.scss etc... By adding the partials into the _utilities-dir.scss for example.

```
utilities
    _utilities-dir.scss
    _functions.scss
    _mixins.scss
    _variables.scss

base
    __base-dir.scss
    _reset.scss
    _typography.scss
```

I then used to use the @import method to create the main.scss file

```
@import "/utilities/utilities-dir",
@import "/utilities/base-dir",
```

How can I create the same output using the new @use method?

Answer (score 0):

With new rule `@use` you need to `@use` the needed file to **EVERY** file where you need to use the vars or methods of that file.

In other words:
It is not enough to `@use` file `utilities-dir` to main file. In that case you can use the vars/methods in main file only. You have to `@use` the files in every partial direct where you want/need the vars/methods ...

As we had that several times: if you like you may have a look to a longer explanation with explaining code scheme example here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/66300336/9268485.