# node sass installation issue

Tags: node.js, sass, node-sass

Node-sass will not install and I've found that this question has been asked a few times but the error messages are different to mine. If I can no longer use this module is there an alternative?

---

```
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142

npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported

> node-sass@5.0.0 install /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wordpress9/wp-content/plugins/recipe/blocks/node_modules/node-sass

> node scripts/install.js

Downloading binary from https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v5.0.0/darwin-x64-79_binding.node
Cannot download "https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v5.0.0/darwin-x64-79_binding.node":

HTTP error 404 Not Found

Hint: If github.com is not accessible in your location try setting a proxy viaHTTP_PROXY, e.g.
export HTTP_PROXY=http://example.com:1234 or configure npm proxy via

      npm config set proxy http://example.com:8080

> node-sass@5.0.0 postinstall /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wordpress9/wp-content/plugins/recipe/blocks/node_modules/node-sass
> node scripts/build.js

Building: /usr/local/bin/node /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wordpress9/wp-content/plugins/recipe/blocks/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=

gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp verb cli [
gyp verb cli   '/usr/local/bin/node',
gyp verb cli   '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wordpress9/wp-content/plugins/recipe/blocks/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js',
gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='
gyp verb cli ]
gyp info using node-gyp@7.1.2
gyp info using node@13.9.0 | darwin | x64
gyp verb command rebuild []
gyp verb command clean []
gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
gyp verb command configure []
gyp verb find Python Python is not set from command line or npm configuration
gyp verb find Python Python is not set from environment variable PYTHON
gyp verb find Python checking if "python3" can be used
gyp verb find Python - executing "python3" to get executable path
gyp verb find Python - "python3" is not in PATH or produced an error
gyp verb find Python checking if "python" can be used
gyp verb find Python - executing "python" to get executable path
gyp verb find Python - executable path is "/usr/local/opt/python@2/bin/python2.7"
gyp verb find Python - executing "/usr/local/opt/python@2/bin/python2.7" to get version
gyp verb find Python - version is "2.7.16"
gyp info find Python using Python version 2.7.16 found at "/usr/local/opt/python@2/bin/python2.7"
gyp verb get node dir no --target version specified, falling back to host node version: 13.9.0
gyp verb command install [ '13.9.0' ]
gyp verb install input version string "13.9.0"
gyp verb install installing version: 13.9.0
gyp verb install --ensure was passed, so won't reinstall if already installed'
gyp verb install version is already installed, need to check "installVersion"
gyp verb got "installVersion" 9
gyp verb needs "installVersion" 9
gyp verb install version is good
gyp verb get node dir target node version installed: 13.9.0
gyp verb build dir attempting to create "build" dir: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wordpress9/wp-content/plugins/recipe/blocks/node_modules/node-sass/build
gyp verb build dir "build" dir needed to be created? undefined
gyp verb build/config.gypi creating config file
gyp verb build/config.gypi writing out config file: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wordpress9/wp-content/plugins/recipe/blocks/node_modules/node-sass/build/config.gypi
gyp verb config.gypi checking for gypi file: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wordpress9/wp-content/plugins/recipe/blocks/node_modules/node-sass/config.gypi
gyp verb common.gypi checking for gypi file: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wordpress9/wp-content/plugins/recipe/blocks/node_modules/node-sass/common.gypi
gyp verb gyp gyp format was not specified; forcing "make"
gyp info spawn /usr/local/opt/python@2/bin/python2.7
gyp info spawn args [
gyp info spawn args   '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wordpress9/wp-content/plugins/recipe/blocks/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-f',
gyp info spawn args   'make',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wordpress9/wp-content/plugins/recipe/blocks/node_modules/node-sass/build/config.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wordpress9/wp-content/plugins/recipe/blocks/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/Users/xxxxxx/Library/Caches/node-gyp/13.9.0/include/node/common.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/Users/xxxxxx/Library/Caches/node-gyp/13.9.0',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wordpress9/wp-content/plugins/recipe/blocks/node_modules/node-gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/Users/xxxxxx/Library/Caches/node-gyp/13.9.0/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wordpress9/wp-content/plugins/recipe/blocks/node_modules/node-sass',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
gyp info spawn args   'build',
gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
gyp info spawn args ]

No receipt for 'com.apple.pkg.CLTools_Executables' found at '/'.
No receipt for 'com.apple.pkg.DeveloperToolsCLILeo' found at '/'.
No receipt for 'com.apple.pkg.DeveloperToolsCLI' found at '/'.


Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wordpress9/wp-content/plugins/recipe/blocks/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py", line 51, in <module>
    sys.exit(gyp.script_main())
  File "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wordpress9/wp-content/plugins/recipe/blocks/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/__init__.py", line 670, in script_main
    return main(sys.argv[1:])
  File "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wordpress9/wp-content/plugins/recipe/blocks/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/__init__.py", line 662, in main
    return gyp_main(args)
  File "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wordpress9/wp-content/plugins/recipe/blocks/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/__init__.py", line 647, in gyp_main
    generator.GenerateOutput(flat_list, targets, data, params)
  File "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wordpress9/wp-content/plugins/recipe/blocks/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/generator/make.py", line 2457, in GenerateOutput
    part_of_all=qualified_target in needed_targets,
  File "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wordpress9/wp-content/plugins/recipe/blocks/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/generator/make.py", line 841, in Write
    self.Pchify,
  File "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wordpress9/wp-content/plugins/recipe/blocks/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/generator/make.py", line 1304, in WriteSources
    arch=config.get('xcode_configuration_platform')
  File "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wordpress9/wp-content/plugins/recipe/blocks/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/xcode_emulation.py", line 661, in GetCflags
    archs = self.GetActiveArchs(self.configname) 
  File "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wordpress9/wp-content/plugins/recipe/blocks/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/xcode_emulation.py", line 515, in GetActiveArchs
    xcode_archs_default = GetXcodeArchsDefault()
  File "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wordpress9/wp-content/plugins/recipe/blocks/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/xcode_emulation.py", line 122, in GetXcodeArchsDefault
    xcode_version, _ = XcodeVersion()
  File "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wordpress9/wp-content/plugins/recipe/blocks/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/xcode_emulation.py", line 1511, in XcodeVersion
    version = CLTVersion()  # macOS Catalina returns 11.0.0.0.1.1567737322
  File "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wordpress9/wp-content/plugins/recipe/blocks/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/xcode_emulation.py", line 1549, in CLTVersion
    return re.search(regex, output).groupdict()["version"]

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groupdict'

gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wordpress9/wp-content/plugins/recipe/blocks/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:351:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:321:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:275:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 18.7.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wordpress9/wp-content/plugins/recipe/blocks/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
gyp ERR! cwd /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wordpress9/wp-content/plugins/recipe/blocks/node_modules/node-sass
gyp ERR! node -v v13.9.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v7.1.2
gyp ERR! not ok

Build failed with error code: 1

npm WARN sass-loader@11.0.1 requires a peer of webpack@^5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN recipe-blocks@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN recipe-blocks@1.0.0 No repository field.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! node-sass@5.0.0 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@5.0.0 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look to this post. There is an actual description how to install/use actual SASS:

[Is it better to use the Live Sass Compiler (VS Code extension) or to install and run Sass via npm? (+ tips how to change from node-sass to dart-sass)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66709895/is-it-better-to-use-the-live-sass-compiler-vs-code-extension-or-to-install-and)

Answer (score 0):

Node 13 isn't supported with node-sass 5.0 as it is end of life. The compatibility table can be found https://github.com/sass/node-sass#node-version-support-policy