# VS Code won't let me compile sass using sass --watch

Tags: css, visual-studio-code, sass, live-sass-compiler

I'm trying to compile sass using the terminal. I already installed node.js, and I didn't have any problem when using Live Sass, however, every time I try to compile my sass I get this:

```
sass : The term 'sass' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.     
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ sass -watch scss:css
+ ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (sass:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I'm trying to use `@use` and I know the Live Sass compiler won't let me do that.
Is there anything I'm doing wrong? Or something else that I need to install?
Oh, I already installed sass using `npm install sass`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Head up: there are several way to use SASS with VS Code. But make sure to use the most actual version running with `Dart SASS`. To install that via NPM here are some information:

[Is it better to use the Live Sass Compiler (VS Code extension) or to install and run Sass via npm? (+ tips how to change from node-sass to dart-sass)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66709895/is-it-better-to-use-the-live-sass-compiler-vs-code-extension-or-to-install-and)

And here are some information about using SASS by installing an VS Code Extension which maybe makes it a little bit mor comfortable to use it:

[Live Sass Compiler - @use causes compilation error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66193156/live-sass-compiler-use-causes-compilation-error/66207572#66207572)

Comment: Thanks, I was able to find a Live Sass Compiler that allows me to use Dart SASS. Haven't finished trying it yet, but I think this will solve my problem, even if I still can't use npm with my terminal.
Link: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=glenn2223.live-sass

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options:

1. Try installing it globally

   npm install -g node-sass
2. Add this the package.json file

   ```
   "devDependencies": {
    "node-sass": "4.5.0"
    },
   "scripts" : {
      "node-sass": "node-sass --output-style compressed -o dist/css src/scss"
   }
   ```

   After that, run:

   ```
   npm i;npm run node-sass;
   ```

Comment: I just tried that, but it just gave a bunch of errors, and honestly, I'm just starting to use the terminal or anything else deeper than plain HTML and CSS.

I want to install dart sass, because Watch Sass doesn't let me use ```@forward``` and ```@use``` and I know that ```@import``` is becoming deprecated. 
Any other recommendations?