# How do you install dart-sass in visual studio code

Tags: sass, dart-sass

I have been using visual studio code (learning web development) with the Live Sass Compiler to compile my sass files into CSS. This has worked great until now. I have started to use the @use instead of @import, BUT I read that it only works with dart sass.

My question is how do you install dart sass and set it up to watch the sass files and compile into CSS?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, that the most popular version 'Live Sass Compiler' is not supported for years.

Yu can use an updated and supported fork ... or there is another extension which make it possible to use your own SASS Version installed on your System (original SASS which is faster) so you are independend from the support.

We had this in another posting so you wil find all information here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/66207572/9268485

Comment: Followed the instructions in the link posted in this answer. Installed the fork of Live Sass Compiler by Glenn Marks. This has worked so far and I am able to compile my sass with the @use into CSS using the Visual Studio Code extension.