# node-sass invalid CSS

Tags: css, sass, node-sass

Does node-sass even support @use ? Since I'm getting this error:

> SassError: Invalid CSS after "...t-family: fonts": expected expression (e.g. 1px, bold), was ".$roboto;"

Here's the code of Nav.scss:

```
.nav {
  width: 100%;
  font-family: fonts.$roboto;

  &__item {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    font-size: variables.$a;

    &_active {
      color: rgb(37, 133, 34);
    }
  }

  &__item:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
  }
}
```

Here's the code of fonts.scss:

```
$roboto: 'Roboto';
```

[image: Here's the file structure]

Comment: completely wrong syntax. https://sass-lang.com/documentation/variables

Comment: where? It's completely right

Comment: Where do you see your syntax anywhere on the page I linked?

Comment: `@use` is only supported by `dart-sass` - if you are using `lib-sass` or `ruby-sass`, that may be why you're getting that error. I believe `node-sass` uses `lib`. Here's a github issue: https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/2886

Comment: @cloned it's under Built-in modules. https://sass-lang.com/documentation/variables#built-in-variables

Comment: @disinfor: If you or Programmer_007 manage to confirm your hypothesis, your comment should be good as an answer.

Comment: haha oh you are right, never used it like this with variables tough, sorry for the confusion. I was on the completley wrong path and confidently incorrect, sorry!

Comment: @BoltClock right on! I will wait until Programmer_007 can confirm before adding as an answer.

Comment: As of your picture I suppose you are using VS Code. In that case you may like to use an extension running most acutal Sass Version 'Dart Sass' so you can use `@use`. Information about that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66207572/9268485

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax is incorrect for node-sass.

You have defined the font variable correctly in fonts.scss but you need to import the font file into your Nav.scss file if you haven't already with:

```
@import "PATH/fonts.scss";
```

You then just need to reference the variable like so:

```
font-family: $roboto;
```