# Visual Studio Code SASS compiler

Tags: visual-studio-code, sass, node-sass

I switch from **Sublime** to **VS Code** because it anymore PHP and SASS support. I mostly use CSS & SASS & JS & PHP.

I set up a SASS compiler from [VS Code documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/css#_step-3-create-tasksjson). As follows:

```css
// Sass configuration
{
  // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
  // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "Sass Compile",
      "type": "shell",
      "command": "node-sass style.scss style.css",
      "group": "build",
      "problemMatcher": [
        "$eslint-compact"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I tested it working properly. **But I have 2 problems:**

1. First of all, it focuses on "style.scss" file. I mean, whatever we mentioned in ".json".

> Actually what I want is: Focus on all ".scss" files without searching for a name.

2. When I run an compile with the "a.scss" editor open, it compiles  only names in the ".json" file. But there not contain "a.scss"!

> Actually what I want is: If I press the "CTRL + SHIFT + B" key and select the corresponding option, the currently active editor is the "a.scss" compilation.

Are there any settings for these?

Note: `"command": "node-sass .scss .css",` it will give error.

Comment: I guess you want something like `node-sass path/to/scss/folder/ -o path/to/css/folder/`. This is probably not something specific to Visual Studio Code. Also, be aware that node-sass is no longer under active maintenance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actual the situation is, that `SASS` actualized to a new version `Dart SASS`. There are new rules like `@use` in it ... so the used compilers needs to be updated.

As I know up to now Node Sass did not.

The better way to use SASS in VS Code is to use an extension.

As we had this several times:
If you are interessted in it you may look here https://stackoverflow.com/a/66207572/9268485

---

Note: if you decide to use one of the extensions your settings may change. Have a look to the extensions descriptions.