# VS code - Live Sass compiler is not updating the css file

Tags: css, sass, visual-studio-code, live-sass-compiler

It was working just fine before. Suddenly **LIVE SASS COMPILER** stopped updating the main.css file. I've reinstalled the **live sass compiler** even ***VScode*** also! Still not working! I'm attaching the SS of the project folder and the settings.JSON file.

[SS of the Project folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJCBo.png)

[SS of the settings.JSON file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZz03.png)

Comment: Does hitting the refresh button work?

Comment: Its `JSON` and not `JASON`

Comment: Nope. Not working! @PhanNhatHuy

Comment: did you have live server installed ? if not  install  Live Server "ritwickdey.liveserver"  as well it should Work

Comment: *,
*::after,
*::before {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: inherit;
}

I mistakenly removed the closing bracket from there...that's why it stopped updating! My bad!

Comment: **Additional note** at that occasion: if you may like to have a look to what version of 'Live Sass Compiler' you have installed. Most popular from Ritwick Dey is indeed(!) not longer maintained and NOT updated and supported (for years now). Actual extension with most actual SASS version (Dart SASS) is the fork 'Live Sass Compiler' from Glenn Marks: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=glenn2223.live-sass. More information about situation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66207572/9268485